# bxSlider not properly reloading after changing src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'm working on a website with a lot of images that are rendered in the default viewport, and therefore we cannot use lazyload. We have a slider with multiple images, where our idea is to only show 1 image, and when the page is fully loaded, change the `src` attribute and reload the `bxSlider`. However after we changed our `src` attributes and reloading the slider, we do not see the images appear on screen.

We've moved around the scripts, tried to include some configuration inside the reload function, but we are unable to get our code to working. The console does not show any errors, and after checking our source code, we can see the `src` attribute is properly changed. We're using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img.hidden').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
        $(this).show(); // The images are on display: none at first
    });
    $('img.hidden').removeAttr('data-src');
    slider.reloadSlider();
});
```

What is the best way to reload `bxSlider` after changing the `src` attributes? Using the above code works for normal images, but I do not know why it isn't working for images in the slider.

Comment: Have you ever considered simply using css to show only the first image then letting bxSlider run when it wants? Or is this not an option?

Comment: @Royalty This is not really an option due to the architecture of the website, unfortunately. I wish we could though! Thanks for the suggestion ^.^

Comment: can you show the code where you are initializing the slider?

Comment: @Royalty Here is a link (its a little bit too much to post it plain here): http://jsfiddle.net/n5p32q8h/

Comment: I guess make sure you also initialize it on document ready, which you are probably already doing. I was thinking maybe it didn't know what slider was at the time. It would have thrown an error then though. Good luck sir. To be sure that this doesn't have to do with loading times I would try running this code in a $(window).load(function() {});

Comment: Thanks @Royalty, we're indeed initializing it on document ready and slider is a valid variable, as we're using it in the same document (and as you say, would throw an error). Thanks for your help, I hope someone else is able to help me further. Edit: What code, the init or the reload?

Comment: 1. Don't set those images to display none! 2. use the CSS intrinsic ratio pattern https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes#specifying-image-dimensions-minimizing-reflows-and-avoiding-page-jumps (no need to reload bxslider) 3. consider using lazyiszes https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes

Comment: @alexandefarkas I've implemented your script and it works great! Thanks for sharing, will be using it much more now I know of it :-)